# Find the polar representation of complex number $ z = 1 + \cos a+ i \sin a$ where $a \in ]0,2\pi[$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I am having difficulty making the case for '$a$' belonging to $]\pi,2\pi[$

Comment: Hint: think at some half-angle formulas.

Comment: Do you know how (and to what extent) you can "write" the polar form of $a+bi$ in general ($a,b\in\Bbb R$)?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $1+\cos(x)=2 \cos^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ and $\sin(x) = 2 \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ so:

$$1+\cos(a)+i\,\sin(a)= 2 \cos\big(\frac{a}{2}\big) \left(\cos\big(\frac{a}{2}\big)+i \sin\big(\frac{a}{2}\big)\right)$$

What's left to figure out is the modulus, and the sign of $\cos\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)$ which conditions the argument.